# Multilabel classifier Prediction using categorical cross entropy loss model

Tags: classification, prediction, multilabel

I am doing a multilabel classification using categorical cross entropy as the loss function.
My input labels are a 1d vector of the form = [2 4 5..]

First I convert my labels to categorical using,

> y_labels = np_utils.to_categorical(y,10)

then I compile the model

> model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy')

Then predict,

> prediction = model.predict(test_data)

This prediction output is of the form,

> [[1 1 2 3 4 2 2 8 7 9]  [2 3 2 5 7 8 5 5 5 4]  [5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5] .
>   . .  [3 4 4 4 6 7 7 5 5 5 ]]

Since my labels are a 1D vector, shouldn't the prediction be a 1D vector as well? Am I missing something here?

My model architecture is as follows,

> ```
> model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(32, 2, 2,activation='relu'),input_shape=(timesteps_lstm,1,5,10)))
> model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(32, 2, 2, activation='relu')))
> model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))))
> model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.25)))
>
> #model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
> model.add(ConvLSTM2D(32,kernel_size=(1,1), input_shape=(timesteps_lstm, 32,1,4 ),return_sequences=False))
> model.add(Flatten())
> model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
> model.add(Dropout(0.25))
> model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
> print model.summary()
> # Compile model
> model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
>
> #Fit model on training data
> model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=5, verbose=0)
> ```

Comment: Could you add your architecture code to the description ?
Once you use np_utils.to_categorical, you'll get N x 10 shape numpy array, your model's output seems to be correct shape, maybe you just want to take argmax on your output

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have added my model architecture. So you are saying that the maximum value in the output size 10  array elements represents the prediction value? i.e. if 9 is the highest value in the output size 10 array element and the location of it in the array is 4, that means the prediction is 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output shape seems to be correct i.e. Batch size x 10

> This prediction output is of the form,
>
> [[1 1 2 3 4 2 2 8 7 9] [2 3 2 5 7 8 5 5 5 4] [5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5] . . . [3 4 4 4 6 7 7 5 5 5 ]]

Are you sure those are the values you are getting? If you are using softmax, each of those values should be between 0 to 1 and each output must sum to 1

Since you apply softmax, those 10 values are the probabilities for each output class, so if you want the most likely prediction, you just need to need to take argmax

```
np.argmax(model.predict(test_data), axis=1)
```

This will give you the class number from 0 to 9 for each test input